# How to add field history and product as a related list of opportunity in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying the below code to add field history and product as a related list of opportunity in vf page, but its not working .

```
<apex:relatedList list="OpportunityFieldHistory"/>
<apex:relatedList list="Product"/>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to write it.

Regards

---

Edit:

There are two Standard objects that have Opportunity history information, [OpportunityFieldHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm) and [OpportunityHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityhistory.htm). The relatedList component works fine with a value of `OpportunityHistories` for the `list` attribute, but an error is thrown when using the value of `Histories`, even though the SObject describe information shows "Histories" as the child relationship name.

```
<apex:relatedList list="OpportunityHistories"/> <!-- Works fine -->
<apex:relatedList list="Histories"/>            <!-- Error -->
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Actually*** ***there are no easy ways to show the Account, Opportunity, Case histories through the `<apex:relatedList/>`***.

Though from the API it is found relationship name is `'Histories'` but those are not accessible through the related List.

We need to have custom coding to display the Opportunity History table.

I have taken the code as provided in this link [History related list in Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095wwIAA) and it is perfectly working.

Hopefully it will help to all Salesforce developers like us.

**Visualforce Component (GenericHistoryComponent)**

```
<apex:component controller="GenericHistoryComponentController">
<!-- Attribute Definition -->
<apex:attribute name="myObject" description="Object we wish to view the history of" type="SObject" required="true" assignTo="{!myObject}" />
<apex:attribute name="recordLimit" description="Number of lines of history to display" type="Integer" required="false" assignTo="{!recordLimit}" />

<!-- Object History Related List -->
<apex:pageBlock title="{!objectLabel} History">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ObjectHistory}" var="History" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Date"  value="{!History.thedate}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="User">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!History.userId}"> {!History.who} </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Action"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!History.action}"/></apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

**Apex Controller (GenericHistoryComponentController)**

```
public class GenericHistoryComponentController {

// External variables
public SObject myObject {get; set;}
public Integer recordLimit {get; set;}
public static String objectLabel {get;}

// Internal Variables
public objectHistoryLine[] objectHistory; 

public static final Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mySObjectTypeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> myObjectFieldMap;
public static List<Schema.PicklistEntry> historyFieldPicklistValues;

public List<objectHistoryLine> getObjectHistory(){
// if no object passed in, return empty list
    if (myObject == null) {
        return new List<objectHistoryLine>();
    }

    Id myObjectId = String.valueOf(myObject.get('Id'));
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescription = myObject.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

    myObjectFieldMap = objectDescription.fields.getMap();
    objectLabel = String.valueOf(objectDescription.getLabel());

    //Get the name of the history table
    String objectHistoryTableName = objectDescription.getName();

    //ID field name         
    string ObjectIdName;

    //if we have a custom object we need to drop the 'c' off the end before adding 'History' to get the history tables name        
    if (objectDescription.isCustom()){            
        objectHistoryTableName = objectHistoryTableName.substring(0, objectHistoryTableName.length()-1);
        ObjectIdName = 'ParentId';        
    }        
    else{
        ObjectIdName = objectHistoryTableName+ 'Id';
    }

if(objectHistoryTableName == 'Opportunity') {objectHistoryTableName = objectHistoryTableName + 'FieldHistory';}
else {objectHistoryTableName = objectHistoryTableName + 'History';}

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult objectHistoryFieldField = mySObjectTypeMap.get(objectHistoryTableName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Field').getDescribe();
    historyFieldPicklistValues = objectHistoryFieldField.getPickListValues();

    list<objectHistoryLine> objectHistory = new list<objectHistoryLine>();

    String prevDate = '';

    if (recordLimit== null){
        recordLimit = 100;
    }

    list<sObject> historyList = Database.query( 'SELECT CreatedDate,'+
                                                'CreatedById,'+
                                                'Field,'+
                                                'NewValue,'+
                                                'OldValue ' +
                                                'FROM ' + objectHistoryTableName + ' ' +
                                                'WHERE ' + ObjectIdName + ' =\'' + myObjectId + '\' ' +
                                                'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC '+
                                                'LIMIT ' + String.valueOf(recordLimit));

    for(Integer i = 0; i < historyList.size(); i++){
        sObject historyLine = historyList.get(i);
        if ((historyLine.get('newValue') == null && historyLine.get('oldValue') == null) 
                || (historyLine.get('newValue') != null && !(string.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).startsWith('005') || string.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).startsWith('00G')))
                || (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null && !(string.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).startsWith('005') || string.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).startsWith('00G')))){
            objectHistoryLine tempHistory = new objectHistoryLine();
            // Set the Date and who performed the action
            if (String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate')) != prevDate){
                tempHistory.theDate = datetime.valueof(historyLine.get('CreatedDate')).format();
                tempHistory.userId = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
                tempHistory.who = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
            }
            else{
                tempHistory.theDate = '';
                tempHistory.who = '';
                tempHistory.userId = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
            }
            prevDate = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate'));

            // Get the field label
            String fieldLabel = GenericHistoryComponentController.returnFieldLabel(String.valueOf(historyLine.get('Field')));

            // Set the Action value
               if (String.valueOf(historyLine.get('Field')) == 'created') {    // on Creation
                   tempHistory.action = 'Created.';
              }
              else if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null && historyLine.get('newValue') == null){ // when deleting a value from a field
                  // Format the Date and if there's an error, catch it and re
                  try {
                     tempHistory.action = 'Deleted ' + Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).format() + ' in <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>.';
                } catch (Exception e){
                     tempHistory.action = 'Deleted ' + String.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')) + ' in <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>.';
                }
              }
              else{  // all other scenarios
                String fromText = '';
                if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null) {
                     try {
                          fromText = ' from ' + Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).format();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                          fromText = ' from ' + String.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue'));
                     }
                }

                String toText = '';
                if (historyLine.get('newValue') != null) {
                    try {
                         toText = Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).format();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                         toText = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue'));
                    }
                }
                if (toText != ''){
                    tempHistory.action = 'Changed <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>' + fromText + ' to <b>' + toText + '</b>.';
                }
                else {
                    tempHistory.action = 'Changed <b>' + fieldLabel;
                }
               }

               // Add to the list
               objectHistory.add(tempHistory);
        }
     }

     List<Id> userIdList = new List<Id>();
     for (objectHistoryLine myHistory : objectHistory){
         userIdList.add(myHistory.userId);
     }
     Map<Id, User> userIdMap = new Map<ID, User>([SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id IN : userIdList]);

     for (objectHistoryLine myHistory : objectHistory){
         if (userIdMap.containsKey(myHistory.userId) & (myHistory.who != '') ){
             myHistory.who = userIdMap.get(myHistory.who).Name;
         }
     }

     return objectHistory;
}    

// Function to return Field Label of a object field given a Field API name
public Static String returnFieldLabel(String fieldName){

    if (GenericHistoryComponentController.myObjectFieldMap.containsKey(fieldName)){
        return GenericHistoryComponentController.myObjectFieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
    }
    else {
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickList : historyFieldPicklistValues){
            if (pickList.getValue() == fieldName){
                if (pickList.getLabel() != null){
                    return pickList.getLabel();
                }
                else {
                    return pickList.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}

// Inner Class to store the detail of the object history lines    
public class objectHistoryLine {

    public String theDate {get; set;}
    public String who {get; set;}
    public Id userId {get; set;} 
    public String action {get; set;}
}
}
```

**Usage of component in Visualforce page (OpportunityRelatedList)**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:pageBlock >
You're looking at some related lists for {!opportunity.name}:
</apex:pageBlock>
<!--it will display Field History -->
```

`<c:GenericHistoryComponent recordLimitAttribute="50" myObjectAttribute="{!Opportunity}"/>`

`<!--it will display Stage History -->`

```
<apex:relatedList list="OpportunityHistories"/>

<!--it will display Opportunity Line Items -->
<apex:relatedList list="OpportunityLineItems"/></apex:page>
```

**Access visualforce page as follows:**

`/apex/OpportunityRelatedList?id=<OpportunityId>`

**Expected Results**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the products you can use:

```
<apex:relatedList list="OpportunityLineItems"/>
```

For the history, take a look at Santanu's answer.

Comment: Hi Fernando...<apex:relatedList list="Histories"/>.. is throwing error.. can u check plz..

Comment: Sorry @user2542953 I just fixed the answer =D

Comment: There is a difference between [OpportunityFieldHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm) and [OpportunityHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityhistory.htm).

Comment: <apex:relatedList list="OpportunityHistories"/> will give only stage history not the field history..

Comment: then how to resolve the issue..

Comment: @user2542953 see my answer, Fernando's answer will not give us expected result.

Answer (score 2):

FYI,
This has been fixed in API versions later than 38.0.  My visualforce page kept on failing with the same error 'Histories' is not a valid child relationship....

My visualforce page was 38.0.  I changed it to 39.0 and now the below line doesn't cause the error.

`<apex:relatedList id="HistoryList" list="Histories" />`