# Case History in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, case, history-tracking

Does anyone know how I can include Case History on a custom VF page on the Case object?  I've tried using the  tag, but that does not work.  I've also tried other solutions using controllers and case.histories fields, but I keep getting a error that oldValue and newValue are not valid fields.  Can anyone help?

**Tried in VF Page:**

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Case History">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!case.histories}" var="c">
        <apex:column headerValue="Date"  value="{!c.createdDate}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="From" value="{!c.oldValue}"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue="to" value="{!c.newValue}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

**Tried Controller:**

```
private final Case chx;

    public list<cHistories> getHistories() {

     list<cHistories> list_ch = new list<cHistories>();

     for (Case ch: [SELECT ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, IsDeleted, Id, Field, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
                    FROM Case
                    WHERE ParentId = :c.id
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]) {

   cHistories ch1 = new cHistories();

       ch1.theDate = String.valueOf(ch.createddate);

       ch1.who = ch.createdby.name;

       if (String.valueOf(ch.Field) == 'created') {

        ch1.action = 'Created.';

       } else if (ch.OldValue != null && ch.NewValue == null){        
        try {
         ch1.action = 'Deleted ' + Date.valueOf(ch.OldValue).format() + ' in <b>' + String.valueOf(ch.Field) + '</b>.';
        } catch (Exception e){
         ch1.action = 'Deleted ' + String.valueOf(ch.OldValue) + ' in <b>' + String.valueOf(ch.Field) + '</b>.';
        }

       } else {

        String fromText = '';
        if (ch.OldValue != null) {
         try {
          fromText = ' From ' + Date.valueOf(ch.OldValue).format();
         } catch (Exception e) {
          fromText = ' From ' + String.valueOf(ch.OldValue);
         }
        }

        String toText = '';
        try {
         toText = ' To ' + Date.valueOf(ch.NewValue).format();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         toText = ' To ' + String.valueOf(ch.NewValue);
        }

        ch1.action = 'Changed <b>' + String.valueOf(ch.Field) + '</b>' + fromText + ' to <b>' + toText + '</b>.';

       }
      list_ch.add(ch1);    
  }
  return list_ch;
    }
    public class cHistories {
        public String theDate {get; set;}
        public String who {get; set;}
        public String action {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include specific examples of what you have tried.

Comment: @Adrian Larson -- OK.  I edited my original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have already given answer on yesterday in this post. Please refer this link:

[How to add field history and product as a related list of opportunity in vf page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/how-to-add-field-history-and-product-as-a-related-list-of-opportunity-in-vf-page/131790#131790)

That post is applicable for showing Account, Opportunity, Case etc. (Standard objects) and other custom object history.

Comment: P.S. if this solves your problem then close this question